# Create model data from firestore and show them by id with different UICollectionView

Tags: swift, model, uicollectionview, tableview, google-cloud-firestore

I have three different collections in Firestore.

I'm appending those data in those [models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETjS2.png) after fetching them from Firestore [with these codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZX8N.png).

My UI is a multiple `UICollectionView` inside multiple `UITableView`. I want to create `collectionView` with packages count and feed them with `JsonStickerPack` models.

This is my code but this one didnt worked because i couldnt correctly feed those `JsonStickerImageEmoji` model. I have to seperate them with something :)

```
        let sp = JsonStickerImageEmoji(imageFile: Stickerdata!, emojis: (packageModel?.description)!)
    let sP1 = JsonStickerPack(stickers: [sp], trayImageFile: trayData!,
                              identifier: docPack.documentID ,
                              name: (packageModel?.name)!,
                              licenseAgreementWebsite: (appX?.licenseAgreementWebsite)!,
                              publisher: (appX?.publisher)!,
                              privacyPolicyWebsite: (appX?.privacyPolicyWebsite)!,
                              publisherWebsite: (appX?.publisherWebsite)!)
    let sP2 = JsonSticker(stickerPacks: [sP1], iosAppStoreLink: (appX?.iosAppStoreLink)!,
                          androidPlayStoreLink: (appX?.androidPlayStoreLink)!)
```

Collectionview codes :

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellReuseId, for: indexPath) as? CustomCollectionViewCell

    print("\(cell?.cellImageView.image)")
    cell?.cellImageView.image = UIImage(data : trayImages[indexPath.row])

    return cell!
}
```

My viewcontroller codes :

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return  categories.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 160
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell") as? CustomTableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
        cell = CustomTableViewCell.customCell
    }
    let aCategory = self.categories[indexPath.section]
    cell?.updateCellWith(category: aCategory)

    cell?.trayImages = trayImages
    cell?.stickerImage = stickerImage
    cell?.stickerInfoArray   = stickerInfoArray
    cell?.stickerPackages    = stickerPackages
    cell?.stickerModel       = stickerModel
    cell?.cellDelegate = self
    return cell!
}
```

This is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92KKI.png) of these codes.

I have to seperate them. Cat to cat etc..